# What does the small number when switching characters means?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA 5, when you switch characters, what is the small number beneath their face mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That number shows how many missions are available for each character at the time.

Comment: Also worth noting that this includes Strangers and Freaks missions as well as story missions.